# Matrix Norms, and Integrals; why is the norm and integral inequality true?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, control-theory, adaptive-control

In my adaptive control textbook that I am using, we are using the following:
$$\left\|\Phi^T\left(\mathbf{x}\right)\Phi\left(\mathbf{x}\right)\right\| \geq \left\|\Phi\left(\mathbf{x}\right)\Phi^T\left(\mathbf{x}\right)\right\|$$

where $\Phi\left(\mathbf{x}\right) \in \mathbb{R}^m$ and are "implicit" functions of time. Then, he claims that the following is true:
$$\alpha_0 I \leq \int_{t}^{t+T}\Phi\left(\mathbf{x}\right)\Phi^T\left(\mathbf{x}\right)d\tau \leq \left(\int_{t}^{t+T}\Phi^T\left(\mathbf{x}\right)\Phi\left(\mathbf{x}\right)d\tau\right)I = \beta_0 I$$
assuming that the integrals are finite. Finally, given the second inequality, we see that

$$\alpha_0 \leq \left\|\Phi\left(\mathbf{x}\right)\Phi^T\left(\mathbf{x}\right)\right\|$$

Where $\alpha_0$ is the infimum of the eigenvalues or less than those of $\Phi\left(\mathbf{x}\right)\Phi^T\left(\mathbf{x}\right)$, which is supposed to be positive definite. Can someone explain why the three inequalities are true?

Comment: How is the norm defined? If it is operator norm over Euclidean norm then they are actually equal.

Comment: When you say operator norm over Euclidean norm, do you mean $\left\|\right\|_2$? Also, can you provide me a proof? Is the proof simple?

Comment: Yes, I meant $\lVert \cdot \rVert_2$. I suspected that this might be a signal norm from the context. Anyway see my answer for the proof.

Comment: If it is signal norm, then does the inequality hold? $\Phi$ is a function of $\mathbf{x}$, which is a vector of states (which is a function of time).

Answer (score 0):

For any real vector $u$ we can show that $\lVert u^T u \rVert = u^T u = \lVert u u^T \rVert_2$.

Note that $uu^Tu=(u^Tu)u$, which means $(u^Tu, u)$ is an eigenpair of $uu^T$. Since it is symmetric and a rank-1 matrix $\lVert u u^T \rVert_2=\rho(uu^T)=u^Tu$ where $\rho(\cdot)$ is the spectral radius.

Comment: Ok. According to my friend, he said this: take $\phi = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2\end{bmatrix}^T$. Then, the eigenvalues of $\phi\phi^T$ are 0 and 5. On the other hand, $\phi^T\phi I = 5I$. Therefore, $\alpha_0 = 5$.

Comment: I couldn't add in the previous comment, so I will add it here: his example is an example of why $\alpha_0 \leq \left\|\Phi\left(\mathbf{x}\right)\Phi^T\left(\mathbf{x}\right)\right\|$.

Comment: You cannot conclude that $\alpha_0=5$, only $\alpha_0 \leq 5$. Take $\alpha_0=4$ and $\beta_0=6$. I believe only existence is enough.

Comment: Why can’t we conclude that $\alpha_0 = 5$?

Comment: You need to check what the claim is precisely. I believe the book claims "there exists $\alpha_0, \beta_0$ such that...", which is true. It doesn't mean $\alpha_0$ is the maximum value it can take.

Comment: Here's what the book says: Since $\left\|\Phi^T\left(\mathbf{x}\right)\Phi\left(\mathbf{x}\right)\right\| \geq \left\|\Phi\left(\mathbf{x}\right)\Phi^T\left(\mathbf{x}\right)\right\|$, it implies that $$\alpha_0 I \leq \int_{t}^{t+T}\Phi\left(\mathbf{x}\right)\Phi^T\left(\mathbf{x}\right)d\tau \leq \left(\int_{t}^{t+T}\Phi^T\left(\mathbf{x}\right)\Phi\left(\mathbf{x}\right)d\tau\right)I = \beta_0 I$$