# Adaptive Control Norm inequality proof

Tags: inequality, vectors, normed-spaces, control-theory, adaptive-control

This is a follow-up question to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3583649/matrix-norms-and-integrals-why-is-the-norm-and-integral-inequality-true).

In my adaptive control book, we are using the following inequality.
$$\left\|\Phi^T\left(\mathbf{x}\right)\Phi\left(\mathbf{x}\right)\right\| \geq \left\|\Phi\left(\mathbf{x}\right)\Phi^T\left(\mathbf{x}\right)\right\|$$

where $\Phi\left(\mathbf{x}\right) \in \mathbb{R}^m$ and are "implicit" functions of time due to $\mathbf{x}\left(t\right)$. In the previous question, they are actually equal if the norm is Euclidean ($p = 2$). Since a control norm is a signal norm in essence, how does one prove that the inequality is true?

Comment: Do you mean that $\|\Phi^\top \Phi\| = \Phi^\top \Phi = |\Phi|^2$ and $\|\Phi \Phi^\top\|$ is the maximum eigenvalue? Or you consider this inequality for any arbitrary norm?

Comment: I think for any arbitrary norm (including $p = 2$).

Comment: I am not so sure that it is true. Let it be the first norm and choose $\Phi = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 2\end{bmatrix}$. Then $\Phi^\top \Phi = 5$ and $\|5\|_1 = 5$. However, $\|\Phi\Phi^\top\| _1= \left\|\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 \\ 2 & 4\end{bmatrix}\right\|_1 =  6$. The same for the $\infty$-norm.

Comment: BTW, I have checked your original question, and I am not sure that the inequalities there are valid without some additional assumption.

Comment: Hello Arastas, sorry for responding to you super late, but if you want, I can provide you the actual source of where I got this.